# Nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu 16.06 - uploaded images not displaying

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean

fellow humans

I have been on this issue for a couple days and would really appreciate some help. So I successfully deployed my app and everything works fine including css and the javascript except for this little thing which Im sure is just a little fix i am missing, resulting to my uploaded images not displaying even tho i see the "upload successful" page.

My image model

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         related_name='images_created')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,
                        blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,
                                            db_index=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                                related_name='images_liked', blank=True)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)




    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('images:detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

my nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 67.207.87.22;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;

    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/kingiyk/stylplus/media;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/kingiyk/stylplus/stylplus.sock;
    }
}
```

my uploaded images are located in /home/kingiyk/stylplus/media/ so atleast i know they were saved.

here is my settings file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))





DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['67.207.87.22', 'styllplus.com', 'www.styllplus.com']



ROOT_URLCONF = 'stylplus.urls'



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stylplus.wsgi.application'









STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/'




from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'



ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: reverse_lazy('user_detail', args=[u.username])
    }

SITE_ID = 1


DJANGO_MESSAGES_NOTIFY = False
```

and here is my html upload page which is supposed to display the image

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}


{% block title %}{{ user.username }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% load thumbnail %}
<div id="lonely">
 {% thumbnail image.user.profile.photo "40" as in %}
    <a href="{{ image.user.get_absolute_url }}">
        <img src="{{ in.url }}" class="gametime"></a>
        {% endthumbnail %}
<a href="{{ image.user.get_absolute_url }}" class="time">{{ image.user.username }}</a>
```

```
<div id="details">
{% thumbnail image.image "551" as im %}

    <a href="{{ image.image.url }}">
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"class="image-detail">
    </a>

{% endthumbnail %}

{% with total_likes=image.users_like.count users_like=image.users_like.all %}
    <div class="image-info">
     <div>
        <span class="count">
            <span class="total">{{ total_likes }}</span>
            like{{ total_likes|pluralize }}
        </span>
        {% with comments.count as total_comments %}

{{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}

{% endwith %}
```

{% if request.user not in users_like %}
                 Like
                {% else %}
                 Unlike
                {% endif %}

```
    </div>
    {{ image.title|linebreaks }}
</div>

<div id="my-chart"></div>
<div class="image-likes">
    Liked by
    {% for user in image.users_like.all %}
        <div>
            {% thumbnail user.profile.photo "30" as in %}
            <img src="{{ in.url }}" class="gametime">
            {% endthumbnail %}
            <a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">{{ user.username }}

        </div>
    {% empty %}

    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endwith %}




{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="image-info">
<p class="info">


    <a href="{{ comment.user.get_absolute_url }}" class="mine">{{      

     comment.user }}</a> {{ comment.comment }}

</p>
```

Every othetr thing works just fine, except for the images not being visible
I can't see what the bug is. I'd appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

you need to add media url and root to tell django where to look for the media if a media file is going to be displayed

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

add this 2 lines in the `settings.py`

adn if you have added `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` in the main `urls.py` then add `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` too as static.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL , document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

add these lines to your urls.py

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
admin.autodiscover()
from django.shortcuts import render
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
url(r'^images/', include('images.urls', namespace='images')),
url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
  

] here my urls.py file. could you clarify more on the urls.py conf.

Comment: after adding this lines in the settings file, doesnt it work??

Comment: it still does not display. plus when i enter the python manage,py collectstatic command, css, js files and some png files get collected and stored at /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static but my uploaded files (mostly .jpg) do not. do you have any idea why that is? I am guessing that could be the root of my problem.

Comment: try the edited ans, after this you need to re-upload a image for media, then check in the templaate

Comment: You are right.I think the problem is from my template <a href="{{ image.image.url }}"> <img src="{{ image.image }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"class="image-detail"></a>when i replace "{{ image.image }}" with {% static "rango.jpg" %}, an image displays but img src="{{ image.image }} doest not display an image. i have a class model named image with an upload_to attribute which uploads my files to /home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/ and in my settings.py, I've got STATIC_ROOT= '/home/kingiyk/stylplus/static/' STATIC_URL= '/static/'. any idea where i went wrong? – P.S-i am in production stage.-DEploy